# Generating a list of two variable names, 41 indices long, with no more than three of the same variable in a row

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, sorting

I need to generate a list of two variable names (large and small). The list needs to be 41 indices long, which provide 40 index transitions between the small and the large variables. No one variable can ever be repeated more than three times in a row. Thus, each list should involve 10 presentations of four transition types: small-small, large-large, small-large, large-small. For example:

```
>>> large = 5

>>> small = 10

>>> L1 = [large, large, small, small, large, large, small, small, small, large, small, large, large, large, small, large, large, small, large, small, small, large, large, large, small, small, large, large, small, small, small, large, large, small, small, large, small, small, large, large, small]
```

I will eventually need to create 10 variations of this kind of list.

The code I have used so far is:

```
import random

S = 5
L = 10
Ratios = [S, L]

Master_List = []

def ListGenerator(List1, List2):
    GeneratedList = []
    random.shuffle(List1)
    for i in List1:
        if len(GeneratedList) < 41:
            GeneratedList.append(i)
        elif len(GeneratedList) == 41:
            break

    for i in GeneratedList:
        List2.append(i)

    return List2


print ListGenerator(Ratios, Master_List)
```

SPECIFIC QUESTIONS

Why is my current code only returning a list of two elements, and how can I evaluate if my list criterion has been met so that I can create my lists of shuffled variables?

Comment: L1 does not have 41 entries?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far and what difficulties are you experiencing? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you probably want to use `random.choices(Ratios, k=41)` to generate the list